# set pipenv_venv_in_project globally

Tags: python, pipenv, virtual-environment

I installed pipenv and I want to set PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT variable globally. So I added PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT variable to my .bashrc by executing the following command : echo "export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1" >> ~/.bashrc.
But this doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean 'environmental variable' when you mention 'global variable'.

Here's how to set the variable:

```
export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1
```

You can check that `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` is set correctly using `echo`:

```
echo $PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT
```